# Error: /partlineswithprefixformat undefined in latex

Tags: pdftex, renewcommand

I am using one of the available template to write my thesis, and i am getting error with /partlineswithprefixformat as undefined. I tried to search for particular package to include, but nothing helped me. Could anyone help me with this?

Particular error is occurring at the stage when /partlineswithprefixformat command is being renewed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `\partlineswithprefixformat` is provided by the KOMA-Script classes `scrartcl`, `scrreprt` and `scrbook`.